# Why website is not accessible by clicking on login button while recording it with proxy server using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, http-proxy

I have set up a proxy server and trying to record a script by adding "http script recorder", but the problem is I am able to access a website but not able to login.

my website has been loaded but once I enter credentials and click on the login button then a website is not behaving, login button also not responding.

Answer (score 0):

In case of any problems with JMeter first of all you should look at [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), if anything goes wrong JMeter normally writes an error message to this log file which in majority of cases is enough to get to the bottom of the issue.

With regards to your problem, my expectation is that login normally uses [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol and you need to perform some extra configuration so JMeter would be able to intercept and decrypt HTTPS traffic.

You need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate to your browser, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start JMeter proxy.

You just need to import it into your browser and it should resolve you issue. Follow your browser documentation to learn more about certificates installation processes, some hints are also given in the **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) JMeter User Manual entry.

Alternative way is using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates so the recording process will be faster and easier.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri for the answer.